# In Mathematica is it possible to define the plot range by an inequality?

Tags: mathematica

For example, like

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, Sin[x]<0.5}]
```

The above line is not working. I want to know if this idea is possible in Mathematica. Thank you!

Comment: This would be better suited to mathematica.stackexchange.com  [ suggest move it there ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure your question is well-defined. One way to proceed is to place a `Boole` around your constraint, e.g. `Boole[Sin[x] < .5]`,  and then plot over standard rectangular co-ordinates of your own choice ... e.g.

```
Plot[Sin[x] Boole[Sin[x] < 0.5], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},  PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I am looking for. Thank you so much!